# Getting PIL image opened with "open" has an empty string as file name

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I named all of the files in my folder, yet when I run the code it simply returns nothing as the file's filename attribute

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Your Program Here")
    images = glob.glob("uncropped/*.jpg")
    for image in images:
        with open(image, 'rb') as file:
            img = Image.open(file)
            print(img.filename)
            print("open")
            input()
```

This code returns nothing as the file name. What should I do?

Comment: couldn't you just `print(image)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're opening the image file yourself with the built-in `open()` and passing that to `Image.open()`. Frankly, I agree the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.filename) is a little ambiguous about this scenario — I suppose a real `file` *is* a "file-like object".

Regardless, if you let PIL open the file it works:

```
import glob
from PIL import Image

folder = "*.jpg"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Your Program Here")
    images = glob.glob(folder)
    for image in images:
        img = Image.open(image)
        print(img.filename)
        print("open")
```

If you really need the attribute to be there for some reason, a workaround is to just add it yourself:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Your Program Here")
    images = glob.glob(folder)
    for image in images:
        with open(image, 'rb') as file:
            img = Image.open(image)
            img.filename = image  # Manually add attribute.
            print(img.filename)
            print("open")
```